# iTunes iPhone Update Error Code 45

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, software-update

I'm trying to update my iPhone 5S to iOS 10.1.1 (current: iOS 9.3.2). I downloaded the ipsw through iTunes and tried updating my iPhone.
However, I am getting error code 45 after iTunes says "extracting software".
My iTunes is up-to-date, and so is my Mac. I did check Apple's error code page but 45 isn't listed there.

Any idea what I could do w/o restoring my iPhone? (I forgot to back it up before updating)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [The iPhone Wiki's website](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ITunes_Errors#Error_45) where it states that Error 45 is:

> Same with Error 6, in terms of resizing partition issue. But this may occur at the very beginning of restore process.

Whereas on Error 6 they write:

> - Not enter the downgrading mode, change USB port (the back one of chassis is better) and restart computer.
> - Unable to resize partition due to full storage problem at final stage of updating firmware. The error may be bypassed (restart and do exit recovery) but you probably need to re-update it one more time.

Comment: Rebooting my Mac and using different usb ports did not change anything.

Comment: @LinusG. the issue states that there might be an issue with resizing the partition, could it be that you're running short on disk space or perhaps you have some permissions issue on your partition?

Comment: I indeed had few space left on the iPhone. Problem only is, now I can't free up any since it's in recovery mode and I can't seem to get it out there doing hard reset or anything.

Answer (score -1):

Error 45 could be done by restore, if you are updating so it will give you the same error 45, so restore your phone.